# Power BI and DAX: How can I show which products a customer has bought [easy], also which products they have NOT bought

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a nice big excel sheet of sales lines - customer, product, date and a bunch of other fields.
 
I can add a visual which shows how many sales by customer and by product, and I used a CALCULATE with CONCATENATEX and SUMMARIZE to define a measure which gives a comma separate string showing the full list of product s which were bought, by customer, for my selected date range, eg:

| Customer | All products Bought |
| --- | --- |
| Amazing | sweets, crisps, donuts |
| BBD corp | crisps, donuts |
| Craazy kidz | donuts |
| Dunking bits | sweets, donuts |

I'd like another col added which displayes all the products NOT bought, ie marketing opportunities:

| Customer | All products Bought | Opportunities |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Amazing | sweets, crisps, donuts |  |
| BBD corp | crisps, donuts | sweets |
| Craazy kidz | donuts | sweets, crisps |
| Dunking bits | sweets, donuts | crisps |

I'd like the table to be flexible so eg if I added a Sweet vs Savoury slicer then it would show just those products which mapped to each of Sweet or Savoury.

Very grateful for any tips

EDIT TO INCLUDE SCREENSHOTS:

[image: visualisation page]

[image: data table]

[image: DAX for concatenation of bought products]

Comment: `EXCEPT(ALL(Products), [expression for table with products the customer bought])` would be your friend here.

Comment: Would you mind explaining a little more what I need to do please? I've had a quick play and can't make it work yet... All the data are in the same table except the sweet/savoury label which is in a linked table, but I think these can be ignored for now

Comment: Can you post your existing formula to get products bought?

Comment: I don't really need to use a formula - I just put the fields into a matrix visual: customer name, product and a simple measure which counts the rows - so I can see a tabulation of the number of orders by product and customer. I've got a measure which concats all the products into a string, but this is irrelevant really as I want a way to identify which products are NOT ordered

Comment: You should use the code suggested by Jeroen above. Unless you can provide a .pbix, it will be difficult for anyone to answer.

Comment: Original post edited to include screenshots

Comment: I'd really appreciate your help Jeroen or David, this feels so simple but I can't make it work